# How to iterate pages of a site from Rails and Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to build an informational site, which shows the visitor all deals from a specific merchant on that specific page. I managed to scrape the headlines from the first page and pack an URL iteration into an array.

My code should take each URL and paste it into the scraper, list the items of that page, iterate to the next page, scrape headlines and attach them to the recent done list, and so on.

My controller looks like this:

```
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  class Entry
    def initialize(title)
      @title = title
    end
    attr_reader :title
  end


  def scrape_mydealz 
    require 'open-uri'
    urlarray = Array.new
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------   URL erstellen
    pagination = '&page=1' 
    count = [1, 2]
    count.each do |i|
        base_url = "https://www.mydealz.de/search?q=media+markt"
        pagination = "&page=#{i}"
        combination = base_url + pagination
        urlarray << combination
    end
    # --------------------------------------------------------------- / URL erstellen

    urlarray.each do |test|
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("#{test}"))
        entries = doc.css('article.thread')
        @entriesArray = []
        entries.each do |entry|
            title = entry.css('a.vwo-thread-title').text
        @entriesArray << Entry.new(title)
       end
   end
    render template: 'scrape_mydealz'
  end
end
```

With this code it iterates to page 2 and displays the scrape result from page 2 only.

The result could be found here:
https://mm-scraper-neevoo.c9users.io/

Comment: thx Nikita, that worked

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We can't run your code and have it show us the problem. We need the _minimum_ code demonstrating the problem, along with the minimum input data that is required to duplicate it and your required output. Without that we have to imagineer data and results which results in inaccurate answers and doesn't help anyone. A link to a result doesn't help us or others as links rot then break resulting in nonsense questions. Remember, SO isn't a discussion list, it's an online reference book for solving problems for others in the future.

Comment: I'd recommend learning to use the URI class to manipulate URIs. It knows how to handle corner cases that will cause problems. Don't do `"#{test}"`. `test` is already a string so use it without sticking it into a literal string and interpolating it. You define `pagination = '&page=1'` then do `pagination = "&page=#{i}"`; drop the first one, but better, learn to use URI and let it build the query. `entry.css('a.vwo-thread-title').text` will cause problems if multiple `'a.vwo-thread-title'` are found. Use `at(...).text` if there is only one or `entry.css(...).map(&:text)`.

Answer (score 0):

You reinitialize `@entriesArray` in each iteration. The easiest solution for you, to move the initialization outside the loop

```
@entriesArray = []

urlarray.each do |test|
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("#{test}"))
    entries = doc.css('article.thread')
    entries.each do |entry|
        title = entry.css('a.vwo-thread-title').text
        @entriesArray << Entry.new(title)
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but it's the general idea I'd use to scan a site with two pages and accumulate the titles:

```
require 'open-uri'

BASE_URL = 'https://www.mydealz.de/search?q=media+markt&page=1'

def scrape_mydealz 

  urls = []
  2.times do |i|
    url = URI.parse(BASE_URL)
    base_query = URI::decode_www_form(url.query).to_h
    base_query['page'] = 1 + i
    url.query = URI.encode_www_form(base_query)
    urls << url
  end

  @entries_array = []
  urls.each do |url|
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    doc.css('article.thread').each do |entry|
      @entries_array << Entry.new(entry.at('a.vwo-thread-title').text)
    end
  end
  render template: 'scrape_mydealz'
end
```

Be careful using `text` with `search`, `css` or `xpath`:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.search('p').text # => "foobar"
doc.search('p').map(&:text) # => ["foo", "bar"]
```

Notice that the first result has concatenated the contents of the `<p>` tags. Trying to take those apart afterwards is not possible usually.